# Adding text and labels to a pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I am very new to LaTeX and `pgfplots`. I would like to reproduce this image:

[image]

Is this possible using `pgfplots`? All I have so far is a straight line!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.70]
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=12,xmax=10, xlabel=independent variable, ylabel=dependent variable]
\addplot coordinates{(2,4) (8, 10)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi Francesca, welcome! That kind of diagram is probably better done with plain `tikz`, no need to use `pfgplots` (although it can be used, obviously). Have you seen the first tutorial chapter of the `tikz` manual? It's a very similar diagram...

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,standalone]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.70]
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=12,xmax=10, 
xlabel=independent variable, ylabel=dependent variable,enlargelimits=0.7]
\addplot coordinates{(2,4) (8, 10)} node[midway,above left] {$d$}
node[pos=0,left] {$A(x_1,y_1)$} node[pos=1,above] {$B(x_2,y_2)$};
\addplot[black,no marks] coordinates{(2,4) (8,4) (8, 10)}
node[pos=0.25,below] {$x_2-x_1$}
node[pos=0.75,right] {$y_2-y_1$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, one could also reproduce your screen shot more closely.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,standalone]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=2, ymax=10,xmin=0,xmax=10,unit vector ratio=1 1, 
xlabel=independent variable, ylabel=dependent
variable,enlargelimits=0.7,grid=major,
xtick={-10,-8,...,20},xticklabel=\empty,
ytick={-10,-8,...,20},yticklabel=\empty,
xlabel={$x$},xlabel style={at=(xticklabel cs:1)},
ylabel={$y$},ylabel style={at=(yticklabel cs:1),rotate=-90}]
\addplot[draw=red,mark=*,mark options=blue] coordinates{(2,4) (8, 10)} node[midway,above left] {$d$}
node[pos=0,left] {$A(x_1,y_1)$} node[pos=1,above] {$B(x_2,y_2)$};
\addplot[black,no marks] coordinates{(2,4) (8,4) (8, 10)}
node[pos=0.25,below] {$x_2-x_1$}
node[pos=0.75,right] {$y_2-y_1$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX.SE !

As Rmano said, you can set your picture with `tikz`. Here is your exact picture in tikz with the corresponding commands :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    %%Set grid and axis
    \draw[step=0.5, help lines] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (4.5,4.5);
    \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node[above]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4.5) node[right]{$y$};

    %%Set scale on the axis
    \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,4}{
        \draw (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1);}
    \foreach \y in {0.5,1,...,4}{
        \draw (0.1,\y) -- (-0.1,\y);}

    \node[fill=blue, circle, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=1pt] (A) at (1.5,1){};
    \node[fill=blue, circle, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=1pt] (B) at (3,3){};
    \draw[red] (A)  -- (B) node [midway, above left, black] {$d$};
    \draw (A) node[left]{$A(x_1,y_1)$} -- (3,1) node[midway, below] {$x_2-x_1$};
    \draw (B) node[left]{$B(x_2,y_2)$} -- (3,1)node[midway, right] {$y_2-y_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the result :

[image]

EDIT :
 I guess the point C is on the third corner. I keep the notation with $C(x_3,y_3)$.
In my opinion, it's better if you labeled the coordinates with the label of the letter : $A(x_a,y_a)$. Tips : Try to modify some stuff on the code to understand the tikz code ;)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %%Set grid and axis
    \draw[step=0.5, help lines] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (4.5,4.5);
    \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node[above]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4.5) node[right]{$y$};

    %%Set scale on the axis
    \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,4}{
        \draw (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1);}
    \foreach \y in {0.5,1,...,4}{
        \draw (0.1,\y) -- (-0.1,\y);}

    %%Set point A, B, C
    \node[fill=blue, circle, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=1pt] (A) at (1.5,1){};
    \node[fill=blue, circle, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=1pt] (B) at (3,3){};
    \node[fill=blue, circle, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=1pt] (C) at (3,1){};

    %%Draw lines and labels on the node
    \draw[red] (A)  -- (B) node [midway, above left, black] {$d$};
    \draw (A) node[left]{$A(x_1,y_1)$} -- (C) node[midway, below] {$x_2-x_1$};
    \draw (B) node[left]{$B(x_2,y_2)$} -- (C) node[midway, right] {$y_2-y_1$} node[right]{$C(x_3,y_3)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: This is fantastic! How would I add the point C at the corner?

Comment: @Francesca could you add an image where the point C appear, please? In your image it is not there.

Comment: Thank you very much! The code you shared is much more advanced than my experience so far. I played around with it before and then weird things started to happen. I appreciate your help!